# Django cascade delete and post_delete signal

Tags: django, django-models, cascading-deletes, django-signals

In my application `post_delete` signals being recorded in a specific model and when it was removed.

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey('A')

class C(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey('B')

def log_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    logging

post_delete.connect(log_delete, sender = A)
post_delete.connect(log_delete, sender = C)
```

When you delete an instance of A cascade delete occurs removing B and C instances. How can I disable signal for child instances on cascade delete by django?

Answer (score 3):

Not an elegant solution as what user2059857 suggested, but a LOT simpler to implement:

Add a field to model A:

```
being_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)`
```

Set this to True when A model pre_delete signal is fired:

```
@receiver(models.signals.pre_delete, sender=A)
def a_pre_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.being_deleted = True
    instance.save()
```

Check if `being_deleted` of your A instance is True in every `pre_delete` of child models and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

You can't.

**Long answer:**

You need to override your `.delete` methods of your `Model` and your model manager `QuerySet`

I have accomplished some similar task by having the instance which the delete was called on passed along by the pre/post delete signals.

Here is the code https://gist.github.com/ar45/9c1448a91bcc94997ff0